# Issue with python code using whisper and speech_recognition: NumbaDeprecationWarning

Tags: python, openai-api, openai-whisper

So, I was trying to test the whisper Openai model with the speech_recognition module in Python, and this error popped up:

```
NumbaDeprecationWarning: The 'nopython' keyword argument was not supplied to the 'numba.jit' decorator. The implicit default value for this argument is currently False, but it will be changed to True in Numba 0.59.0. See https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit for details.
```

Can anyone help me, please?

I tried to change the code, but I can't get it right

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error but a simple warning. Just read what it says:

> The 'nopython' keyword argument was not supplied to the 'numba.jit'
> decorator. **The implicit default value for this argument is currently
> False, but it will be changed to True in Numba 0.59.0**.

It literally says that in the actual version of Numba you use, if you provide not value for the "nopython" argument in the cited decorator, this argument will be set to False by defaut; and they inform you that this behavior will change in a next version of Numba '0.59.0' (from that moment on, the default value will be set to "True").

So if you want to avoid any surprise when upgrading this library, you'd better explicitly set the "nopython" argument to the value that suits your needs.

And it also give you the link to the explanation: https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit.

I strongly advise you  read it, since it will help you choose the best value for "nopython" argument.

Generally speaking, don't be afraid to read the error messages you get, they are here to help you. I know nothing about numba at all, but the message is explicit enough to understand what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I used `PYTHONWARNINGS=ignore whisper...` to get this warning to hide. Updating to the latest version of whisper also handled it tho.